Labeling a bar chart in Latex
I have the following bar Chart in Latex:
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            symbolic x coords={CRITICAL, HIGH, MEDIUM, LOW},
            x tick label style={rotate=50, anchor=north east},
            ymin=0, 
            bar width=0.8cm,
            nodes near coords, 
            axis x line=bottom,
            axis y line=left,
            enlarge x limits=1,
            ylabel={Anzahl},
        ]
        \addplot[draw=black, fill=red] coordinates {(CRITICAL, 3)};
        \addplot[draw=black, fill=orange] coordinates {(HIGH, 17)};
        \addplot[draw=black, fill=yellow] coordinates {(MEDIUM, 33)};
        \addplot[draw=black, fill=blue] coordinates {(LOW, 54)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Severity from the difference between Grype/Snyk and Docker Scout}
    \label{balkendiagramm_grype_scout}
\end{figure}

I get this:

I would like the text to be centered under the bar. Furthermore, HIGH should also be listed. The last LOW should also be removed. How can I do this?
A bar chart with thes 3 Requirements.

I think this will help you.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{subcaption}% Offers an user interface to sub-captions.
\usepackage{float}% Improves the interface for defining floating objects
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        symbolic x coords={
            CRITICAL, 
            HIGH, 
            MEDIUM, 
            LOW},
        xtick={CRITICAL,HIGH,MEDIUM,LOW},
        x tick label style={rotate=50,anchor=east},
        bar width=0.8cm,
        nodes near coords, 
        nodes near coords align={vertical},
        axis x line=bottom,
        enlarge y limits=0.1,
        enlarge x limits=0.2,
        ybar=-0.8cm, % because of bar width=0.8cm
        ymin=0, 
        axis y line=left,
        ylabel={Anzahl},
    ]
    \addplot[draw=black, fill=red]    coordinates {(CRITICAL, 3)};
    \addplot[draw=black, fill=orange] coordinates {(HIGH, 17)};
    \addplot[draw=black, fill=yellow] coordinates {(MEDIUM, 33)};
    \addplot[draw=black, fill=blue]   coordinates {(LOW, 54)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Severity from the difference between Grype/Snyk and Docker Scout}
\label{balkendiagramm_grype_scout}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

Result

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
